# How to show differences between entities and database table structure

Tags: mysql, database, spring, entity-framework, hibernate

I am currently working on a system that has been around for a number of years and has gone through a fair amount of transformation. (GWT\Spring\Hibernate). I recently had to merge two entities as part of a change. When I looked at the actual sql tables I noticed that there were a number of orphaned columns that were actually not mapped to the entities and could effectively be dropped. I was wondering if there are any tools out there that would help us to identify and strip out outdated columns which are not actually being linked to our entities.

Answer (score 0):

If you´re Using Spring and hibernate you can use autodetection to create/update database though the entities attributes that you have in your entity.

your hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto setting should be defining that the database is created (options are validate, create, update or create-drop)

Here the Spring configuration:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Icarus"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
    </properties>
    <class>net.interaxia.icarus.data.models.ServerNode</class>
</persistence-unit>
```